# Python Alt Hooking

Tags: python, hook, alt, pyhook

I was writing this type-recording program when I encountered a problem - <kbd>Alt</kbd> key doesn't have an Ascii number so I can't hook it in the regular way.
This is my source code without the <kbd>Alt</kbd> hooking try, the question is - how do I hook <kbd>Alt</kbd>?
I know that there is Class variable named "Alt" and built-in function named "IsAlt" but I didn't get how to use them.

```
import pythoncom,pyHook

log = ""
logpath = "log.txt"

openfile = open(logpath,"w")
openfile.write("")

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    try:
        global log
        if event.Ascii == 8:
            log = "[BS]"
        elif event.Ascii == 9:
            log = "[TAB]"
        elif event.Ascii == 13:
            log = "[NL]"
        elif event.Ascii == 27:
            log = "[ESC]"
        elif event.Ascii == 15:
            openfile.close()
            exit()
        else:
            log = chr(event.Ascii)
        openfile.write(log)
    except:
        pass

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: I believe on each KeyboardEvent you have to check whether `event.Alt` is also set to detect whether the Alt modifier key was held down at the same time. I would suggest running the [example](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial#Keyboard_Hooks) code and observing what event data is generated for different key combinations.

Comment: thanks, it was realy helpful!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy hooking! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **event.Ascii** when mapping keys, use **event.KeyID**.

Note that keys like **AltGr** have 2 mapping IDs: one for pressed key and another for released key.