# Script in Python crashed when alt+tab is pressed repeatedly (pyhook and pythoncom)

Tags: python, pyhook, pythoncom

I'm making a script in Python 3.5.2 on windows 10 that capture the keys that user press.The code works perfectly except when I press alt+tab to switch the windows, sometimes crashes immediately and sometimes crashes when I press it repeatedly.

The most basic code is next:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print ('Ascii:', event.Ascii, chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
# create a hook manager
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
# watch for all keyboard events
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()
#wait forever
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

There is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MXW61I-2_A&feature=youtu.be) with the poblem.

I don't want to stop the script at any circumstance. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your video is private, make it unlisted.

Comment: I'm sorry, now it's public.

Comment: On SO it is expected to keep your question self contained without external links. Please describe your problem properly instead of making a video. Being able to describe the problem is an important part of solving it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494234/python-alt-hooking